# How do I curtail my url tags in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have many a long list of URLs in a navigation bar in a Django template.

```
<a href="{% url animals.views.bear %}">The Big Bad Bear</a>
<a href="{% url animals.views.cat %}">The Cat</a>
<a href="{% url animals.views.dog %}">The Dog</a>
...
```

How do I avoid repeating `animals.views.` before each URL template tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag:

```
{% with av=animals.views %}
<a href="{% url av.bear %}">The Big Bad Bear</a>
<a href="{% url av.cat %}">The Cat</a>
<a href="{% url av.dog %}">The Dog</a>
{% endwith %}
```

The proper way, however, would be to set the proper names on your URL confs, just as Alex described.

Answer (score 2):

you can name your urls : [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url)

in your urls.py:

```
import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^bear/$', views.bear, name="bear"),
    url(r'^cat/$', views.cat, name="cat"),
    url(r'^dog/$', views.dog, name="dog"),
    ...
)
```

then your template code will look like:

```
<a href="{% url bear %}">The Big Bad Bear</a>
<a href="{% url cat %}">The Cat</a>
<a href="{% url dog %}">The Dog</a>
...
```

but remember, that it is convinient to name your urls using app prefix, in your case `animal`